# How to replace column value in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to change the column value in asp.net using data tables. For example if column contain value 0 I want to show some message instead of 0. Here is the code.

```
if (!this.IsPostBack)
{
    DataTable dt = this.GetData();
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

    html.Append("<table class='table table-hover'>");
    html.Append("<tr>");
    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        html.Append("<th style='text-align: center;'>");
        html.Append(column.ColumnName);
        html.Append("</th>");
    }
    html.Append("</tr>");

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        html.Append("<tr style='text-align: center;'>");
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        {
            html.Append("<td>");
            html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
            html.Append("</td>");
        }
        html.Append("</tr>");
    }

    html.Append("</table>");
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
}
```

Here is the record that I am getting in web page.

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlgv2.png)

Comment: You do not seem to have any replacing code yet. Any particular blocker?

Comment: i didn't understand what you said

Answer (score 1):

You can put condition where you are generating html with `DataTable` data. If DataTable cell value is "*0*" you can replace it with any string e.g. "*Zero Value*" in example given as below.

```
foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
{
    html.Append("<td>");
    if(row[column.ColumnName].ToString() != "0")   
        html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
    else
        html.Append("Zero Value");   
    html.Append("</td>");
}
```

**Edit** Based on Comment by OP, add one more condition on ColumnName in the if statement.

```
if(column.ColumnName == "status" && row[column.ColumnName].ToString() == "pending")
```

Comment: i want to first check if the column name called "status" value is zero then show "Pending"

Comment: You can add that in condition in if statement, see me answer.

Comment: Yes, @WaleedIkhlaq you first need to compare if the column name is "status" or not. If it is status then check if it value id "Zero" or not. then instead of `html.Append("Zero Value");` you can show `html.Append("Pending");`.

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
{
  html.Append("<td>");
  if (row[column.ColumnName].ToString() != "status" && row[column.ColumnName].ToString() != "0")
     html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
  else
     html.Append("Pending");
  html.Append("</td>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make check condition if there is value contain zero?

```
foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
{
    html.Append("<td>");
    html.Append(column.ColumnName == "status" 
        ? (row[column.ColumnName].ToString() != "0" 
            ? row[column.ColumnName].ToString() 
            : "Pending") 
        : row[column.ColumnName].ToString());   
    html.Append("</td>");
}
```

Also you can use ISNULL funciton from SQL server if possible.

Comment: this lines makes all the records value pending